# Is there any significance to horse color in the Naruto world?

Tags: naruto

I'm watching the Naruto spin off titled *"Rock Lee and His Ninja Pals"* and during episode one, Lee says:

> *Just think of me as your hero riding in on a black horse!*

Tenten then slaps him away and exclaims:

> *It's a white horse, idiot! Black horses are for the bad guys!*

To which Neji follows up with:

> *Interesting.*

Now, I've done *some* research and [Wikipedia](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/White_horses_in_mythology) makes a similar implication that white horses generally have a positive portrayal:

> *White horses have a special significance in the mythologies of cultures around the world. They are often associated with the sun chariot, with warrior-heroes, with fertility (in both mare and stallion manifestations), or with an end-of-time saviour, but other interpretations exist as well.*

However, I can't find a reputable (to my knowledge) source of information on the common portrayal of black horses. I *did* find [one article](https://worldbirds.com/horse-symbolism/#:%7E:text=The%20black%20horse%20totem%20is%20an%20emblem%20of%20death%20and%20rebirth.) that mentions their *totems* being omens of death:

> ***The black horse totem is an emblem of death and rebirth.** Its purpose is to aid you in leaving unnecessary things behind and showing you new opportunities that await. For this, it is required to take a risk and have faith.*

Additionally, searches related to horse color within the context of Naruto have yielded no results.

##### Clarifications

As requested in the comments, the timestamp for when this happens is 6 minutes and 27 seconds in.

---

Is there any significance to horse color in the Naruto world?

<sub>*Perhaps we need a tag for the spin off?*</sub>

Comment: Do you perhaps have a timestamp for when in the episode this happens?

Comment: @Dimitrimx updated my question with the timestamp :)

Comment: Is there any reason to think it's more than the horse equivalent of a black hat vs a white hat?

Comment: FYI, there is a tag for Naruto spin off: [tag:naruto-gaiden]

Comment: @FumikageTokoyami that is a specific spin-off, unrelated to this one.

Comment: @Mary, that's what I'm thinking it is, but I wanted to try and double-check to see if maybe I missed something.

Comment: I wonder if it's somehow meant to be correlated to Yin/Yang, white being positive/light whereas Yang is negative/dark